# How can i make VIM show the prototype for a function , while using omnicomplete plugin?

Tags: vim, plugins

I wanted VIM to show the function prototype , while i triggered the auto-complete function , the window should be like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------
Small window , show things like:  void dummy (int du , int d2 );
-----------------------------------------

void dum ^X^O , and a drop down list to pick function


-----------------------------------------
```

Is this possible ? or something similar can be found ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the preview option set in completeopt?

```
set completeopt+=preview
```

this should give you a small preview window when completing.

Comment: Just one thing , can i make it more pleasant , e.g display only: void dummy ( ... ) ?

Comment: To force the preview window to always show the function prototype, I use `set completeopt=menuone,preview`.